# Dropping extra decimal places in c

Tags: c, double, decimal, extra

I've run into a small problem. I'm trying to remove extra decimal places in c, that will be used in calculations.

For example 67.98345, 
I want it to be 67.98

But not just for a printf statement. I need the double to actually be 67.98 not 67.98345

Comment: “I need the double to actually be 67.98” You are in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

@mvp's answer is okay, but it has a minor problem. The intermediate value of the multiplication can overflow the double if x is close to the maximum double magnitude. An alternative that fixes this problem is:

```
double intpart, fracpart;

fracpart = modf(x, &intpart);
x_rounded = intpart + round(fractpart * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will round to the nearest value:

```
double x_rounded = round(x*100)/100;
```

For completeness, these will round down or up:

```
double x_rounded_down = floor(x*100)/100;
double x_rounded_up   = ceil (x*100)/100;
```

Comment: Note you must `#include <math.h>` for this to be correct, and that if x is near the maximum double magnitude you can get overflow of the intermediate result so that the answer will be +-inf.

Comment: Considering that max double value is `1.7977e+308`, you only encounter this problem if `x > 1.7977e+306` - which would be fine with most people